# Finding the velocity of a given wavepacket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I've been given a wave packet, that is moving from right to left toward a (known) potential, which has in time $t = 0$ has the form:

$$ψ(x, t = 0) = Ae^{−c(x−x_0)^2}e^{ik_0x}$$

and I need to calculate (numerically) it's evolution in time. All the parameters ($x_0, k_0, c, A, \hbar, m, b, a$) are known, and I need to solve for two potentials:
$$V_1(x) = −10\hbar^2/(m^2b^2)(Θ(x + b) + Θ(−x + b) − 1)$$

$$V_2(x) = −\hbar^2/(m^22a^2){\rm sech}^2(x/a)$$

My problem is that I don't know how fast the packet is moving. I was told I can derive this from $k_0$, but I'm not sure how. How can I know it's velocity depending on it's form at a single moment alone?

Comment: Do you have you have the potential explicitly, if so what is it?

Comment: I added the potentials.

Comment: I don't think you need to find out how fast the wavepacket is moving to do the numerical simulation. Just set up something that does a time-step evolution of Schrodinger's equation.

Comment: That said, if you really want to know the velocity of the wavepacket, you can find the expectation value of the momentum, $\int dx \psi^*(x)(-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx})\psi(x)$. Once you know the average momentum, you can determine the average velocity.

Comment: Just to make sure, the velocity will simply be $p/m$ ?

Comment: In any case, I already tried to simply use the time evolution operator on the wavepacket. It did evovlved, but it's center didn't move.

Comment: I think that means you have a bug in your time evolution operator. The time evolution operator should be all you need; you definitely SHOULDN'T include the velocity of the wavepacket explicitly.

Comment: Even though I don't know the time dependence?

Comment: Okay, so I checked my code again, and turns out I had a bug. To calculate the Time-Evolution operator I used the function "exp" in matlab, instead of "expm". And turns out the wave packet is actually moving just by applying the time evolution.
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score -1):

Use the momentum operator with $\hat p = -i\hbar\partial/\partial x$  on the wave $\psi(x,t) = Ae^{-c|x - y|^2}e^{ikx}$ and compute the velocity as
$$
v\psi = -\frac{i\hbar}{m}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Ae^{-c|x - y|^2}e^{ikx} = -\frac{\hbar}{m}(k - 2ic|x - x_0|)\psi
$$
The $x_0$ is the start condition and so I would have the initial velocity $v = \hbar k/m$.

Comment: $x_0$ is not the "start condition", it is just the center of the wavepacket. You certainly can't assume $x=x_0$ when calculating the velocity or momentum. You need to do $\langle \psi | P |\psi\rangle$. You can't just do $P |\psi\rangle$ and then try to guess your way to a solution.

Comment: You are right, it is the center of a Guassian distribution --- my bad.